# Java functions delete() and renameTo() not deleting nor renaming

Tags: java, delete-file, file-rename

```
public void newEditSportRecord(){
    String filepath = "sport.txt"; //exists in C:\Users\Dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment\
    String editTerm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID of Sport you wish to modify:");
    
    String tempFile = "temp.txt"; // to be created in C:\Users\Dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment\
    File oldFile = new File(filepath);
    System.out.println(oldFile.getAbsolutePath()); // prints C:\Users\Dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment\sport.txt
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);
    System.out.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath()); // prints C:\Users\Dell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Assignment\temp.txt
    String ID, name = "";

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        
        while (x.hasNextLine()) {
            ID = x.next();
            System.out.println(ID);
            name = x.next();
            System.out.println(name);

            if (ID.equals(editTerm)) {
                newID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new Sport ID:");
                newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new Sport Name:");
                pw.println(newID);
                pw.println(newName);
                pw.println();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(modifySport, "Record Modified");
            } else {
                pw.println(ID);
                pw.println(name);
                pw.println();
            }
        }
        x.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        oldFile.delete();
        File dump = new File(filepath);
        newFile.renameTo(dump);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(modifySport, ex);
    }
}
```

I have the following function to try and modify a text file. However, it does NOT delete the original file "sport.txt" nor does it rename "temp.txt" to "sport.txt". It DOES read from the file and create a copy of "sport.txt" with all the relevant modifications as "temp.txt". I had suspected it was a problem with the writers but having closed all of them, the issue still persists. Is this simply down to permission problems as the folder exists in the Documents folder on Local Disk?

Comment: Well, you should check the return value of both methods since that would indicate whether the operation succeeded or not. If it failed the reason could be permissions, the file being locked (opened by some other application) or something else. JavaDoc on `renameTo(File)` states: "The return value should _always_ be checked to make surethat the rename operation was successful." Alternatively use `Files.delete()` and `Files.move()` to get an exception which should provide more information as to why the operation failed.

Comment: `String other = "D:/sport.txt";
File otherFile = new File(other);
otherFile.delete();
System.out.println(otherFile.delete());`
So I have tried to manually move the file to another directory. Using the delete() function successfully deleted that file but returned a "false" in the command line so now I am even more confused? @Thomas

Comment: Look at the code you've posted there: you're calling `delete()` twice so if the first call succeeds the second should fail since the file has already been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a permission problem. Either change the permission of the Documents folder and give access to all the permissions to your user or change your working folder.